# RabbitMQ Exchange and Queue are not created automatically

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have created a new spring application which will push messages to a rabbitmq server.
My rabbitMQConfig java file looks like this :

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RabbitMQConfig.class);

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host}")
    private String SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.port}")
    private int SPRING_RABBITMQ_PORT;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username}")
    private String SPRING_RABBITMQ_USERNAME;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password}")
    private String SPRING_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD;

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(){
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST,SPRING_RABBITMQ_PORT);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(SPRING_RABBITMQ_USERNAME);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(SPRING_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD);
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setExchange("my.controller.exchange");
        rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey("my.controller.key");
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    DirectExchange exchange() {
            return new DirectExchange("my.controller.exchange", true, false);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
            return new Queue("my.controller", true);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding exchangeBinding(DirectExchange exchange, Queue queue) {
            return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("my.controller.key");
    }
}
```

Here is how I push message to the queue :

```
@Service
public class RabbitPublisher {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RabbitPublisher.class);

    public  Boolean  pushToMyQueue(HashMap<String, Object> message) {
        try {
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("my.controller.exchange","my.controller.key",message);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.error("Error in pushing to my queue", e);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Since the exchange and queue are non-existent on the rabbitmq server, I expect them to be created automatically and message to be pushed. But it results in the following error :

```
ERROR 18198 --- [168.201.18:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : 
Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>
(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 
'my.controller.exchange' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
```

When I create the exchange and queue and bind them manually on the server, a message gets pushed successfully.
Please let me know if I am missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a RabbitAdmin @Bean. The admin will declare the elements when a connection is first opened.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add AmqpAdmin admin bean with your required connection factory as below:

```
   @Bean(name = "pimAmqpAdmin")
    public AmqpAdmin pimAmqpAdmin(@Qualifier("defaultConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    }
```